# Google map with search integrate in to wix website

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I need to integrate google map in to Wix with following circumstances.

1. Address auto completion field. (the field must create via wix element)
2. The address field must have auto completion facility.
3. When input a address, it should mark on the map.
4. When map dragged, the center coordinates should pass to another text field in wix site.

I did lot of searches and didn't find a proper way to do this.
I completed the dragged part is using `window.parent.postMessage` and it's working find.

the issue is how can i create this auto completion address field

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [AddressInput](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/addressinput) element is what you're looking for.